# How to hide div which has specific class on cloned element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having two li(left and right li, initially left li was empty). First scenario When i click right li that wants to add to left li and need to remove from right. Second scenario When i click left li that wants to add to right li on the same position and need to remove from left li. I did it. But

Right side li have facility name, Account number, address line and task count but i want to show the facility name, Account number and task count in the left side. When i click left li that wants to add to right li with facility name, Account number, address line and task count information.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qXT9Z/86/

Is it possible to hide the div which has the class="address_line" after clone(only for first scenario)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can clear all classes from the element by setting `className` to `""`:</s>

```
element.className = "";
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/emaqil/) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/emaqil/edit)

That will probably result in an element that has a `class` attribute which is blank, which is probably good enough for your purposes. If you really need it to not have a `class` attribute *at all*, you could use [`removeAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-6D6AC0F9) to remove it:

```
element.removeAttribute("class");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/emaqil/2) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/emaqil/2/edit)

Some older versions of IE have a bug where they may want you to use the string `"className"` rather than `"class"` with `removeAttribute`, even though that makes no sense.

**Sorry**, you said you were using jQuery, didn't you? The jQuery versions of the above are:

Just removing the class (possibly leaving others):

```
elementWrapper.removeClass("address_line");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/emaqil/3) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/emaqil/3/edit)

Completely removing the attribute via jQuery's [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
elementWrapper.removeAttr("class");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/emaqil/4) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/emaqil/4/edit)

Comment: @crowder thanks for your response. Sorry i asked my question as wrong manner. Now i edited my question. I want to hide the div which has the class "address_line" in my clone element

Comment: @crowder thank you so much. I did this by  liClone.find(".address_line").hide(); Your code was inspiration to me from your code only i learned how to handle clone. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qXT9Z/88/

Comment: @vinothini: Always put the relevant code **in the question itself**. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question